# Finding the Bases of the given subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W_1 = \{( a_1 , a_2 , a_3 , a_4 , a_5)\in F^{5} \mid a_1 - a_3 -a_4 = 0\}$ .

I read the solution somewhere which straightaway says that the set : $\{ (1,0,1,0,0) , (1,0,0,1,0) , (0,1,0,0,0) , (0,0,0,0,1) \}$ is a basis for $W_1$, and hence $\dim W_1 = 4$. But how to find this set?

Using the conditions given for $W_1$, any $x$ belonging to $W_1$ can be written as $(r+s,p,r,s,t)$, for $r,s,p,t$ belonging to $F$, using this how to find the bases?
Kindly help!

Comment: using your parametrization setting $r=1,s=p=t=0$ gives the first basis vector, and similarly setting one of $r,s,p,t$ to $1$ and all others to $0$ gives each of the other 3 basis vectors.  You can do this whenever you have a parametrization (which you can think of in this case as a linear map from $F^4 \rightarrow  F^5$, which is a bijection onto $W_1$) by seeing where your parametrization sends the standard basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(r+s, p,r,s,t) = r(1,0,1,0,0) + p(0,1,0,0,0) + s(1,0,0,1,0) + t(0,0,0,0,1)$$